# Why "show more comments" when less than 6 comments in chrome?

Tags: bug

There is an issue about "show more comments" in chrome.

The example is this question: [How to undo the most recent commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/927358)

In Firefox, everything is normal. But in Chrome, this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6376039/7700501

only have 3 comments, but it only shows 2 comments with the 3rd one hidden. I think it is supposed to show every comments because there are less than 6 comments in total.

And the comments following the question only shows 4 comments, is it supposedly to show 5?

Is this a bug with Chrome? How do I know in chrome comment hiding is actually showing the right thing. Some posts are fine but this post is wrong.

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Firefox, I get the " show 1 more comment" button on that answer for the reasons explained in Kendra's answer.

Comment: @DavyM But in my Firefox, it shows 3 comments without "show 1 more comment", it is Firefox 61.0.1 for Ubuntu. How about yours?

Comment: 61.0.1 for Windows 10 (64-bit). Are you possibly using a link to the comment on that answer? For example, [This link shows the "show 1 more comment" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-most-recent-commits-in-git/6376039#6376039) however [this link makes the comment show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-most-recent-commits-in-git/6376039#comment90304091_6376039) for me.  This is because the first link is to the answer, but the second is to the hidden comment.

Comment: @DavyM No I'm using the link to the answer in Firefox and it shows me comments with 0 score. Maybe this is a bug from SO?

Comment: This is weird... I just tried it on Chrome (67.0.3396.99) and Microsoft Edge (42.17134.1.0), and it also shows the "show 1 more comment" button, however Internet Explorer (11.165.17134.0) it displays the hidden comments by default just as you describe. So there is some variance between browsers. (Although I'm pretty sure no one tries to support IE nowadays.) There must be some difference in Firefox for Ubuntu that isn't present in Firefox for Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this is expected. Because of the number of answers on that question, comments without any upvotes are automatically hidden regardless of the number of comments. This is intended to help save real estate on the page, given that the important information *should* be in the posts themselves.

If it's working differently in Firefox, that might well be a bug.

Comment: it is very interesting to know about that. so you are saying that it is actually correct in chrome, and it is the design by SO that to only show comments with score > 1, instead of the top 5 comments normally implemented? Do you have any reference to this policy?